# I'm trying to loop checkboxes and radios but I can't figure it out?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to show an alert message depending on if checkboxes and radios are checked or not. My problem is that this code only works if all checkboxes/radios are checked or unchecked, if I skip one it still alerts checked. What am doing wrong? I've tried to look at some previous questions about this subject.

```
document.querySelector('#id').addEventListener('click', (e) => {   
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$('element#id').find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked') && !$('element#id').find('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked')) {
      alert('not checked')
      return false;
    } else {
      alert('checked')
    }
  })
```

I've also tried this, if I only check one it alerts "checked", if non is checked nothing happens when I press the button...? Maybe there is an easy solution to this problem? :-)

```
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('element#id input[type="checkbox"]:checked, element#id input[type="radio"]:checked');
  for(var i = 0; i< inputs.length; i++){
    if(inputs[i].checked){
      alert('checked')
    }else{
      alert('not checked')
    }
  }
```

This is my html markup

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1" class="myclass">
<input type="checkbox" id="2" class="myclass">
<input type="checkbox" id="3" class="myclass">
<input type="checkbox" id="4" class="myclass">
<input type="radio" id="5" class="myclass" name="a"><input type="radio" id="6" class="myclass" name="a">
<input type="radio" id="7" class="myclass" name="b"><input type="radio" id="8" class="myclass" name="b">
<input type="radio" id="9" class="myclass" name="c"><input type="radio" id="10" class="myclass" name="c">
<input type="radio" id="11" class="myclass" name="d"><input type="radio" id="12" class="myclass" name="d">
<input type="radio" id="13" class="myclass" name="e"><input type="radio" id="14" class="myclass" name="e">
<input type="radio" id="15" class="myclass" name="f"><input type="radio" id="16" class="myclass" name="f">
<input type="checkbox" id="17" class="myclass">
<input type="checkbox" id="18" class="myclass">
```

If I run this with all inputs checked I get 18 `true`, not checked 18 `false`.
My goal is that all of the checkboxes must be checked, one of the radios in each pairing must be checked. If you miss one checkbox or radio you get a alert/warning. Hope this explains a little bit more :-)

```
 const checkboxElement = document.querySelectorAll('.myclass');
    checkboxElement.forEach(item => {
      console.log(item.checked)
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try using `.forEach` when using `querySelectorAll`, and you mentioned `else` wasn't working so try `else if`. Also, I've made it select by class `.myclass`. Like this:

```js
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('element#id input[class="myclass"]');
inputs.forEach(input=>{
    if(input.checked) {
        alert('Checked');
    } else if(!input.checked) { // try this. using an `else if` because you mentioned above `else` isn't working
        alert('Not Checked');
    }
});
```

This should fix the problem along with making the code look cleaner.
Let me know if it doesn't work.

`forEach` is a function, it takes an argument which is a callback. The first argument of the callback is the element in the list. It iterates through the list which you ran `forEach` on and runs the callback for every iteration.

Here's an example:

```js
["answering", "stackoverflow"].forEach(text=>{
    console.log(text);
});
// result:
// answering
// stackoverflow
```

The result will be:

```
answering
stackoverflow
```

*Developer Note*: **Use semi-colons.**

Comment: I've tried `forEach` and `else if` but still nothing when I press the button with unchecked radios/checkboxes. And only one checkbox needs to be checked for the `forEach` loop to be true.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.. @Dalle

Comment: I displayed some html markup and my problem :-)

Comment: Added some changes, it should work now. Just replace 'myclass' with the unique class that ONLY your checkboxes & radio inputs have

Answer (score 0):

This will be an easy solution for your need

```js
 const checkboxElement = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');
  
 function changeCheckbox() {
   const isCheckedAll =  Array.from(checkboxElement).every(el => el.checked)
    if(isCheckedAll) {
      return alert('checked')
    } else {
      return alert('not checked')
    } 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input class="checkbox"
       type='checkbox' 
       onChange="changeCheckbox()">
 <input class="checkbox" 
        type='checkbox' 
        onChange="changeCheckbox()">

</body>
</html>
```

Ext Link: https://jsbin.com/vanobifora/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: I've tried`const checkboxElement = document.querySelectorAll('.classname');

    const isCheckedAll =  Array.from(checkboxElement).every(el => el.checked)
    if(isCheckedAll) {
      return alert('checked')
    } else {
      return alert('not checked')
    } ` but it returns `not checked` even when the are checked

Comment: did you check all ? I am sure you got confused with the alert() can you replace it with console.log and see the output

Comment: I can't check all because several of the checkboxes are radios and you're not allowed to check more than one in each pair, see the code above.

Comment: how to identify each pair?